# how to calculate time between button press and button release in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, desktop-application

```
public void shotPower() {
    float startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (Gdx.input.getCurrentEventTime(Input.Keys.S)){
            float endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            float time = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

this code doesn't work.

I press button "S" and than press it for some time, I don't know how to calculate time between press and release. Maybe such method allready exists. I understand that it somehow connect with System.currentTimeMillis. Please help.

Sorry for my English, and I'm only begin to learn programming.

Comment: I believe `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a `long`, or `unsigned long`... You can check the documentation...

Comment: Also, a button have some events - button pressed and button released (check documentation for precise names). You probably will need to listen to both to get start time and end time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently calculating the time it takes between the if statement, which will be very close to zero

Use an [InputProcessor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) instead. You will then have access to the methods `keyDown()` and `keyUp()` which you can use to compare the time. As both methods can't share local variables and we have multiple keys I'm using a HashMap to store the  data.

```
// integer is keycode, long is the time it was pressed
private HashMap<Integer, Long> keyTime = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keyCode) {

    keyTime.put(keyCode, System.currentTimeMillis());

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keyCode) {

    if(keyTime.containsKey(keyCode) {
        float time = endTime - keyTime.get(keyCode);
        System.out.println(time);
        keyTime.remove(keyCode);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public long isPressed() {

```
    long time = 0;

    long time1 = 0;

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)) {

        time = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

        System.out.println(time);
    }
return time;
}
```

That should work, only need time in seconds.